# Integration kafka consumer under existing .net core web application

Tags: .net, apache-kafka, asp.net-core-webapi, kafka-consumer-api

I have a web application(.net core 6.0)
I is composed by three projects: api (contain program.cs and controllers), BLL (Repositories and services), ADL (entities and models)
I implemented .net kafka consumers as a service in the project BLL
When I add bellow lines in my program.cs,
`builder.Services.AddHostedService<ConsumerService>();`
`builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, ConsumerService>();`
the consumer works fine but the apis will available only after consuming queued messages. When I send new message using producer, they will not be consumed.

This the code of my consumer class:

```
 public class ConsumerService :  IHostedService
    {
        private readonly string topic = "test";
        private readonly string groupId = "test";
        private readonly string bootstrapServers = "localhost:9092";
        private MemberRepository memberRepository;
       

        public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var config = new ConsumerConfig
            {
                GroupId = groupId,
                BootstrapServers = bootstrapServers,
                AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Latest
            };

            try
            {
                using (var consumerBuilder = new ConsumerBuilder<Ignore, string>(config).Build())
                {
                    consumerBuilder.Subscribe(topic);
                    var cancelToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
                    try
                    {
                        while (true)
                        {
                            var consumer = consumerBuilder.Consume(cancelToken.Token);
                            var model = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ModelErp>(consumer.Message.Value);
                            // code sync with database
                        }
                    }
                    catch (OperationCanceledException)
                    {
                        consumerBuilder.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

**Hint :** my builder is typed WebApplicationBuilder

I expect that my API will be available also my consumer will consume any messages.

Comment: Finally I resolved by issue by using BackgroundService  instead of  IHostedService based on this code https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/master/examples/Web/RequestTimeConsumer.cs